# Конструкция Int.TryParse в С#. Есть ли аналогичная конструкция в Swift или Kotlin?

Tags: c#, android, ios, swift, kotlin

Есть ли аналоги конструкции Int.TryParse?

```
static int inputAndCheckValue()
{
    int tempInput = 0;
    bool resultParse = false;
    while (!resultParse)
    {
        resultParse = (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out tempInput));
        if (!resultParse)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error");
        }
    }
    return tempInput;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В kotlin есть похожий метод [`toIntOrNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-int-or-null.html)

Например

```
println("Hello, world!!!".toIntOrNull()) // выведет null
```

[**playground**](https://pl.kotl.in/BQsDSoQqZ)